# Estimate size of restored DB

Tags: sql-server, database, database-restore

The amount of free space on my machine is limited, and I'd like to know how many dbs I can fit on it before restoring them.

So given a .bak file, how can I estimate how big its restored database on SQL server will be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This output:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'c:\path\file.bak';
```

Has a `Size` column (in bytes). You can perform math to extrapolate from there, for example let's say the results in that column are:

```
3211264
 802816
```

These are in bytes, and expressed in KB (at least how Windows Explorer exposes it) would be:

```
3211264 + 802816) / 1024 = 3,136 KB
```

And in MB would be:

```
3211264 + 802816) / 1024 / 1024.0 = 3.0625 MB
```

You may want the `SUM` of the whole column, or you may want to `RESTORE ... WITH MOVE` and place different files on different drives if you have the ability to do so, in which case you'll want to consider different files separately.